# Get access to a view inside each row of ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, togglebutton, onclicklistener

I have a `ListView`, and for each row of the `ListView` I have an `ImageView`, 2 `TextView` views, and 1 `ToggleButton`.

How can I access the views within a row (e.g. the `ToggleButton`)?

I've tried using an `OnClickListener`, but it didn't work and I don't know why. Below is what I've tried:

```
 @Override
 public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position, long id){
    ToggleButton tb2 = (ToggleButton)parent.findViewById(R.id.star);
    if(tb2.isChecked()){
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "TOOGLE BUTTON TEST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

My row layout:

```
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:paddingBottom="8dip"
    android:paddingTop="5dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/contact_user" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="fill"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameClient"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/accountClient"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#483ca0" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/star"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/list_star_selector"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:textOff=""
        android:textOn="" />

</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
ToggleButton tb2 = (ToggleButton)view.findViewById(R.id.star);
```

`ListView parent` is the parent view, `View view` is the view you actually clicked and contains the subviews you need

Comment: Hello mihail. Thanks for your reply. But don't work this way. I update my question with my xml for each row of listView. I don't know what is the problem....

Comment: do the debugger stops in the onClickListener if you add a breakpoint? Is there any value in the tb2 after the findViewById ?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `parent` is your list view, while `view` is the view that was clicked within the ListView. You can use `view` or (from android's documentation): Subclasses can call getListView().getItemAtPosition(position) if they need to access the data associated with the selected item.

Answer (score 0):

one way is you can define listener in your custom adapter class

and

second way is

ToggleButton button=(ToggleButton)view.findViewBtId(R.id.star);

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position, long id){
    ToggleButton tb2 = (ToggleButton)view.findViewById(R.id.star);
    if(tb2.isChecked()){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "I clicked the ToggleButton on row " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Try that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend actually setting the onClickListener to the background of the view in the getView() of your adapter. By doing this you can get access to the convertView which is recycled as the list view scrolls and can modify it according to your state.

Also, make sure to set it after you have set the tag of the view so that it doesn't recycle your listener and give you strange bugs. =)